# Pandas explode function not working for list of string column

Tags: python, pandas

To explode list like column to row, we can use pandas [explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#exploding-a-list-like-column) function. My pandas' version '**0.25.3**'

The given [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#exploding-a-list-like-column) worked for me and another answer of Stackoverflow.com works as expected but it doesn't work for my dataset.

```
    city        nested_city
0   soto        ['Soto']
1   tera-kora   ['Daniel']
2   jan-thiel   ['Jan Thiel']
3   westpunt    ['Westpunt']
4   nieuwpoort  ['Nieuwpoort', 'Santa Barbara Plantation']
```

**What I have tried:**

```
test_data['nested_city'].explode()
```

and

```
test_data.set_index(['nested_city']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
0    ['Soto']                                  
1    ['Daniel']                                
2    ['Jan Thiel']                             
3    ['Westpunt']                              
4    ['Nieuwpoort', 'Santa Barbara Plantation']
Name: neighbors, dtype: object
```

Comment: Please check the `nested_city` is list or string ?

Comment: 1: Do you get any error? in that case you might want to check the pandas version , 2: check if they are actual lists (`test_data['nested_city'].apply(type)` ) or just string representation  of a list in which case do `test_data['nested_city'].apply(ast.literal_eval).explode()`

Comment: `type(test_data['nested_city'])` returns, pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: test_data['nested_city'].apply(type) check the output

Comment: `test_data['nested_city'].apply(type)` showing `0 <class 'str'>......
Name: neighbors, dtype: object`

Comment: @AlwaysSunny that is the reason `<class 'str'>` , not list type, explode is for list type

Comment: @anky 1. No error, my pandas version is 0.25.3, 2. `test_data['nested_city'].apply(ast.literal_eval).explode()` seems working for me

Comment: just a last query, how to explode multiple columns at a time, is it possible

Comment: I would recommend some time invested in the understanding the python dtypes supported by various methods, also for your last query you need a loop with `df.join` check documentation. I will leave it to you as a homework :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to ensure that your column is of list type to be able to use pandas' `explode()`. Here is a working solution:

```
from ast import literal_eval

test_data['nested_city'] = test_data['nested_city'].apply(literal_eval) #convert to list type
test_data['nested_city'].explode()
```

To explode multiple columns at a time, you can do the following:

```
not_list_cols = [col for col in test_data.columns if col not in ['col1', 'col2']] #list of columns you are not exploding (assume col1 and col2 are being exploded)
test_data = test_data.set_index(not_list_cols).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

Comment: If you get an exception from `literal_eval` make sure your columns are a string representation of a list -`test_data['nested_city'] = test_data['nested_city'].fillna({i: [] for i in test_data.index})` and `test_data['nested_city'] = '[' + test_data['nested_city'].astype(str) + ']' `