# pandas | list in column to binary column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
+------------+------------------+
| item       | categories       |
+------------+------------------+
| blue_shirt | ['red', 'white'] |
+------------+------------------+
| red_skirt  | ['blue', 'red']  |
+------------+------------------+
```

and I want to get this instead:

```
+------------+-----+-------+------+
| item       | red | white | blue |
+------------+-----+-------+------+
| blue_shirt | 1   | 1     | 0    |
+------------+-----+-------+------+
| red_skirt  | 1   | 0     | 1    |
+------------+-----+-------+------+
```

here is what I tried:

```
orders = orders.join(pd.get_dummies(orders['Categories'].explode()))
```

it creates the right columns however it creates (a lot) of additional rows too. I want one row in the end for each item like in the example above.

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve this problem with a one-liner using *.str* method of pandas

```
df['categories'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
```

The format within each cell of *'categories'* column needs to be a list. If it's a string of something else, you can make it a list with an .apply function. For example, if content of *'categories'* column is a list saved as a string:

```
df['categories'].apply(lambda x: eval(x)).str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the categories and the pivot the dataframe:

```
print(
    df.explode("categories")
    .pivot_table(
        index="item", columns="categories", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0
    )
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
categories        item  blue  red  white
0           blue_shirt     0    1      1
1            red_skirt     1    1      0
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, as it reduces the number of rows.. I don't know why? It also makes it so each item has 'red' set to more than 1 but I want binary columns (1 or 0)

Comment: @mokiliiiLo Can you post dataframe you're working with? I used the one you have in question.

Comment: i can't as it's too big and confidential data.

Comment: @mokiliiiLo Just reduce it to a minimal sample that doesn't work with `explode`/`pivot_table`

Comment: This does not work if you don't specify an index. If you do and there are empty lists in the column, the final index won't match with the original data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get to your desired outcome with the below approach.

**Step 1:**  creating a list of columns that will be used in your resulting dataset.

```
>>> cols = list(set(df['categories'].explode())) #set makes sure we keep unique columns
>>> cols.insert(0,df.columns[0]) 

cols
Out[359]: ['item', 'red', 'white', 'blue']
```

*OPTIONAL: You can make sure  `explode()` works by converting your column to list type:* [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63472664/pandas-explode-function-not-working-for-list-of-string-column)

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['categories'] = df['categories'].apply(literal_eval) # convert to list type
```

**Step 2:** use your code with `pd.get_dummies()`, and create the 1/0 dataset. To avoid getting more rows, I added an additional step using `groupby.index`:

```
>>> temp = pd.get_dummies(df['categories'].explode())
>>> temp_res = temp.groupby(temp.index).sum()

Out[365]: 
   blue  red  white
0     0    1      1
1     1    1      0
```

**Step 3:**, I `concat` your 'item' column, with the above result, and used the column list created in the first step to get your desired result:

```
>>> out = pd.concat([df['item'],temp_res],axis=1,ignore_index=False)
>>> out = out[cols]

Out[368]: 
         item  red  white  blue
0  blue_shirt    1      1     0
1   red_skirt    1      0     1
```

**All the code in 1 block**:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['categories'] = df['categories'].apply(literal_eval) #convert to list type

cols = list(set(df['categories'].explode()))
cols.insert(0,df.columns[0]) 

temp = pd.get_dummies(df['categories'].explode())
temp_res = temp.groupby(temp.index).sum()

out = pd.concat([df['item'],temp_res],axis=1)
out = out[cols]
```