# How transform list of strings in column and split dataframe by same string to have several?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column containing list of strings.

```
id sentence                                            category
0  "I love basketball and dunk to the basket"          ['basketball']
1  "I am playing football and basketball tomorrow "    ['football', 'basketball']
```

I would like to do 2 things:

- 1. Transform category column where every elements from previous list become a string and have one row for each string and with same id and sentence
- 2. Have one dataframe by category

Expected output for step 1):

```
id sentence                                            category
0  "I love basketball and dunk to the basket"          'basketball'
1  "I am playing football and tomorrow basketball"     'football'
1  "I am playing football and tomorrow basketball"     'basketball'
```

Expected output for step 2):

DF_1

```
id sentence                                            category
0  "I love basketball and dunk to the basket"          'basketball'
1  "I am playing football and tomorrow basketball"     'basketball'
```

DF_2

```
id sentence                                            category
1  "I am playing football and tomorrow basketball"     'football'
```

How can I do this ? For each and examine len of each list can work, but is there a more faster/elegant way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `explode` "category"; then `groupby`:

```
out = [g for _, g in df.explode('category').groupby('category')]
```

Then if you print the items in `out`:

```
for i in out:
    print(i, end='\n\n')
```

you'll see:

```
   id                                        sentence    category
0   0        I love basketball and dunk to the basket  basketball
1   1  I am playing football and basketball tomorrow   basketball

   id                                        sentence  category
1   1  I am playing football and basketball tomorrow   football
```

Comment: Clearly, the guts of the problem are resolved with this answer... however, we can get cute with the output.   The object that is the result of a `groupby` can be iterated through and we can cheese that into a dictionary: `dict((*df.explode('category').groupby('category'),))`

Comment: @piRSquared I thought of creating a dictionary but went with a list because I wanted to show the print output. But yeah, that's a nice point (and groupby object is a strange thing; has to be unpacked to be cast into a dict)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need two tools : [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

First let's prepare our data, and ensure explode will work with [literal_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63472664/pandas-explode-function-not-working-for-list-of-string-column) :

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from ast import literal_eval

csvfile = StringIO(
"""id\tsentence\tcategory
0\t"I love basketball and dunk to the basket"\t["basketball"]
1\t"I am playing football and basketball tomorrow "\t["football", "basketball"]""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

df.loc[:, 'category'] = df.loc[:, 'category'].apply(literal_eval)
```

Then explode regarding your category columns :

```py
df = df.explode('category')
```

Finally, you can use `groupby` as a dictionary and store your sub dataframes elsewhere :

```py
dg = df.groupby('category')

list_dg = []

for n, g in dg:
    list_dg.append(g)
```

Imo, I will stick with `dg` if possible

Comment: The main problem-solving component of this answer has already been provided by another answer.  However, you provided a useful tool to get the sample data into a dataframe.  This also brings up a possible point of ambiguity that the OP may not have realized.  That being that the dataframe could contain strings that look like list literals or actual lists.